# Wait for the file to be downloaded and then continue

Tags: excel, vba, delay, sap-gui

I am facing the following problem.  The current active workbook is the `VBRK.XLSB`. In this file I have written the VBA code. I have connected the SAP with EXCEL and I am trying to download a SAP table to spreadsheet to file `EXPORT.XLSB`. Then I would like to activate the extracted file.
The problem is that macro activates the current file `VBRK.XLSB` because it takes some time to download and open the extracted file `EXPORT.XLSB`.

Please find below the code I have written.

Thank you very much for your help.

Is there a way for the macro to wait until the extracted file `EXPORT.XLSB` is downloaded, opened, and then continue executing?

```
Sub SAP_TABLE()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NZSE16"
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_TABLE").Text = MainWS ' "VBRK"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI_TABLE").caretPosition = 4
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[3]/menu[2]").Select
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[14]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,5]").Selected = False
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,15]").Selected = True
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,10]").Selected = True
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/chk[2,10]").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI1-LOW").Text = "GR40"
Sheets(CfgWs).Select  ' gia na parei tis imerominies
On Error Resume Next
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-LOW").Text = Range("c5") '"01.02.2023"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-HIGH").Text = Range("c6") '"28.02.2023"
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-HIGH").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtI2-HIGH").caretPosition = 10
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
'load table
Session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
'create spreadsheet
Session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
Session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 43
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmbG_LISTBOX").Key = "31"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\Users\USER1\_Tables MainFolder\Export\"
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").caretPosition = 0
Session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 4
Session.findById("wnd[2]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
Session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press

Dim aa
For aa = 1 To 30 Step 1
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
Next aa

MsgBox ("activeworkbook = " & ActiveWorkbook.Name)

End Sub
```

Comment: add a wait loop, something like wait until current time plus 2 minutes.

Comment: could you please provide me a sample of code ?   I have tried but the result was the same.  The loop has run and when it stops macro did not recognized the extracted file.

Comment: Does the downloaded file open in the same instance of Excel where your code is running, or does a new instance of Excel open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I assume your process itself works)

Check the ActiveWorkbook within the loop - increase the counter if 30s sometimes is not enough. If ActiveWorkbook is the expected file, you can leave the loop. Also, you should leave the loop after a certain time to prevent an endless loop when download failed.

```
Const TimeOut = 120   ' 2 minutes.
Const Exportfile = "EXPORT.XLSB"

(...)

Dim timeCounter as Long
For timeCounter = 1 To TimeOut Step 1
    DoEvents
    If ActiveWorkbook.Name = Exportfile Then
        MsgBox Exportfile & " downloaded in " & timeCounter "s."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Next timeCounter 

If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> Exportfile Then
    MsgBox "A timeout occurred downloading " & Exportfile
End If
```

Comment: I added the code after my code. I see that while loop is running macro nothing happens. When loop is completed, then  the macro extracts the file and opens it.   I would like some how to give a command to say to excel to wait and sap continue with extracting the file. And it shows as active  workbook after the loop the VBRK file.

Comment: I guess you will need to add a `DoEvents`, try the corrected code.

Comment: I added in the line before dim .. now I placed it in the loop .. let's see !!!